# PHP Call to a member function on a non-object when I call a method outside its class

Tags: php

So in my php script I have a function in my database class whichchecks if the user exists. This function is being accesed outside the class. The database.php file is being included in the header.php file, which is then being included in the modal_login.php file. The function has to return something all the time. But the problem is is that I get this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function validate_user_from_db() on a non-object in templates/modal_login.php on line 24
```

here's the database class:

```
class database {
    private $connection;

    function __construct() {
        $this->connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
    }

    private function exec($query) {
        if($link == false) {
            $msg = "no connection";
            return $msg;
        } else {
            $result = $this->connection->query($query);
            $this->validate($result);
            return $result;
        }
    }

    public function validate_user_from_db($where_value, $where_value2) {
      $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE email =  '". $this->connection->real_escape_string($where_value) ."' AND password = '". $this->connection->real_escape_string($where_value2) ."'";
      $results = $this->exec($query);
      if($results != "no connection") {
          return $this->fetch_array($results);
          var_dump($results);
      } else {
        $msg = "Nope.";
        return $msg;
      }
    }

    private function validate($query_result) {
        if(!$query_result)
            die('Query error: ' . mysqli_error($this->connection));
    }

    private function fetch_array($results) {
        return mysqli_fetch_array($results);
    }

}

$db = new database();
```

modal_login.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['subm'])) {
    $user_results  = $db->validate_user_from_db($_POST['email'], $_POST['password']);
}
```

This is how I include my code:

init.php:

```
include 'functions.php';
include 'modules/database.php';
include "config.php";
```

header.php:

```
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/init.php");
```

content page:

`include "templates/header.php"
   include "modal_login.php"`

this is what var_dump($db) says:

string(7) "name_of_db"

Can somebody please tell me what I overlooked here?

Comment: The error says it all, `$db` isn't an object.

Comment: but how? I defined it right below the class

Comment: use `$GLOBALS['db']` to avoid scope issues

Comment: I'm just getting started with OOP in PHP, but anyways see my updated question.

Comment: So, does anybody know a possible answer, besides referring to some frameworks?

Comment: Look for wherever you're setting `$db = anything`, somewhere you're setting it to that string. (Illustrative of why globals are anti-patterns.) My apologies, I thought I was helping with the concepts. Good luck. `:)`

Comment: look at weird `$link` that always non-strict `false` there

Comment: what? @Deadooshka

Comment: @JaredFarrish how can I prevent it from being a string? the only time I define $db is in database.php and it's this: $db = new database();

Comment: @Deadooshka is referring to the `$link` variable being undefined in the `exec()` method and hence always false (so `exec()` never runs the query), see https://3v4l.org/v4f57. However, that's not the problem, since `exec()` isn't getting called at all. Something is setting `$db =` that database name (globally). See: https://3v4l.org/28nDZ You might check where you may have a condition like `if ($db == 'name_of_db')`. it can sneak in if it's actually `if ($db = 'name_of_db')`.

Comment: The problem with globals is, you can't prevent it. Hence, the anti-pattern and aversion to globals most OOP developers have. They're unsafe and easily collided with accidentally, causing difficult to find bugs like this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it, I had to define $db in modal_login.php and not in database.php

This worked for me.